# How do I find out my computer network name (Linux)?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, hostname

I have a linux machine on my university network where I usually log in via ssh from home. I have know the ip, so this is what I use to log in, but it would convenient to know if my computer have a hostname on the local network (it's easier than remembering the ip).

I set up a hostname when I installed linux on my pc, but it's not the name associated with that ip on the network. Is there a way to find out if there's a name associated with that ip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a computer that is using the University's DNS servers, you can try `ping -a x.x.x.x` (Windows) or `host x.x.x.x` (Linux).

If your University's DNS servers are not set up for dynamic DNS entries, you will **not receive a name for the host**. I'm suprised your University allows SSH connections (or allocates you public addresses) for that matter. You may want to set up your own name using [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/).

Answer (score 6):

You can try `nslookup`.

```
nslookup 192.168.0.1
```

Substituting the IP address you use, of course.